# SSD death reinstall windows 10 with existing windows 7 key

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation, product-key

My SSD is totally dead. Really dead, i can't see it in the explorer connected over USB, it's not shown in the BIOS, it's not shown in a linux live environment.. Really dead.

So the problem is that my Windows 10 on this SSD was upgraded from Windows 7 and I forgot to extract the new Windows 10 key from the SSD. Now I have a death SSD with the Windows 10 Key, and the old Windows 7 Key which was already used when I upgraded Win 7 to Win 10.

Is it possible to install a clean Windows 10 to a new SSD and activate it with the already used Windows 7 Key?

I definately can not rescure the SSD, it is dead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows 10 key was a generic key. When you install Windows 10 again on a new SSD, leave the product key field empty during setup and Windows will reactivate itself, because a hash of your hardware was submitted to Microsoft activation servers.

Comment: Luckily there are some really ingenious people working at microsoft! Thank for your help!